# how to make an new array from keys of an associative array in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an array whose value when i print out comes out in these way

```
Array ( 
        [q1] => Array ( 
                        [0] => stdClass Object (
                            [student_unique_id] => 6 
                            [studentname] => studentname 
                            [studentpassword] => 1213 
                            [dob] => 09/05/16 
                            [studentenrollmentnumber] => 1341243124 
                            [studentcontactnumber] => 9460930479 
                            [studentemailid] => abhisehk@mail.com 
                            [studentdepartmentname] => department of agriculture 
                            [studentpasswordtstatus] => 0 
                        ) 
                    ) 
        [q2] => Array ( )
)
```

when i use the code `print_r($prar);`these all values of array are coming from database and i am using an mvc framework codeigniter.Now i need to split the array into 2 new arrays using key.Sorry if it sounds stupid but i am new here!

Comment: can you split 2 new array using `q1` and `q2` keys?

Comment: @razibalmamun sorry but i am novice and i dont have idea which function to use to do so?

Comment: Can you put here sample output how you want?

Comment: @VijaysinhParmar  i want to make sure the key q1 in array becomes an new array in itself and key q2 becomes an second array in itself!

Comment: @AbhishekJoshi Please provide your output in comment box what you are want.

Comment: @AbhishekJoshi. I have provided with a clear explanation about your doubts and how to rectify it. Have a try and share thoughts on it. If you face any hindrance let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** When you use the `print_r()` it will output the array with `stdClass Object` in CI when you are pulling out a value from the Database.

There is a solution to display the array without using the `stdClass Object` while iterating.

**Example:** Consider `$final` consider the array and while using `print_r()` it displayed the  `stdClass Object`.

- You have to use the loop as follows so that it avoids the `stdClass Object` while printing it.

**Code:**

This code you can use it for the values to retrieve from the DB using the Controller and Model.

> If single row of the output is retrieved from the DB

```
<?php
foreach($final->result() as $single)
{
   //You can print the variable values over here as follows (E.g) echo $single->id    
}
?>
```

> If Multiple row of the output is retrieved from the DB

```
<?php
$row=array();
foreach($final->result() as $single)
{
   //You can store it as an array here if you are going on with multiple loops
   $row[] = $single; 
}
print_r($row); // here you can save it as an another array
?>
```

### How should the model Code look like if you are using `->result()` in the foreach to get the values

Here is the sample that your model should look like if you are using the above methods for the retrieving of the output.

**employee_model.php**

```
<?php
class Employee_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

public function getEmployees()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('employee');
    $this->db->where('delete_status','0');
    $this->db->where('status','1');
    $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
?>
```

### How to call the model from the controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends Layout_Controller {

public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library("pagination");
     $this->load->model('employee_model');
     $this->load->model('ajax_model');         
 }

 public function employee_listing()
 {
     $result['all_employee'] = $this->employee_model->getEmployees(); // getEmployees is the function name in the employee_model
     $this->load->view('frontend/employee_list',$result);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try bellow code :

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($prar as $key=>$val) {
    $new_array[] = $val;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
```

or A possible use for extract() is to import into the symbol table variables contained in an associative array returned by wddx_deserialize().

```
extract($prar, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($q1);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($q2);
echo "</pre>";
```

The above example will output:

```
[0] => stdClass Object (
                            [student_unique_id] => 6 
                            [studentname] => studentname 
                            [studentpassword] => 1213 
                            [dob] => 09/05/16 
                            [studentenrollmentnumber] => 1341243124 
                            [studentcontactnumber] => 9460930479 
                            [studentemailid] => abhisehk@mail.com 
                            [studentdepartmentname] => department of agriculture 
                            [studentpasswordtstatus] => 0 


)

Array ( )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hope so it is better to use the method which i have suggested since it will be the safest method to get rid of `stdClass Object`. And it is an extra process to store another `array()` as it takes more time for the execution of the code. Hope so you could understand better from my explanations.